# How can remove a row in bindView without changeCursor?

Tags: android

I use ViewHolder pattern in CursorAdapter.

How can remove a row from listview completely and fix position.

```
@Override
    public void bindView(final View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {

        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        holder.tvText.setText(cursor.getString(holder.column_gtext)).

        final int myId = cursor.getInt(holder.column_id);

        holder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {             
                dbHelper.delete(myId); // delete from database successfully.
                // remove row from listview completely.       
            }
        });
    }
```

**I would not use the swapCursor and changeCursor or LoaderManager. (localy)**